# How is a PHP application able to fetch huge data via MySQL which exceeds max_allowed_packet value

Tags: php, mysql

Am optimizing a script. One of the idea is to fetch around 3 million rows via a Select and save on further multiple "Select"s (sending queries again and again vs doing it once). So my max_allowed_packet is 32 MB and each row has on an average 50 bytes. So, when I did the math, I got a number around 655 thousand that should fill up the 32 MB space.

So was just wondering how does MySQL manage to send data even larger than the max packet size. The maximum that I was able to fetch (and have the heart to try) is 6 million rows.

Source - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html

Would appreciate your help on this as once I understood this, I'd be able create a proper fallback (remember, the idea is to optimize and not tear it up.)

Comment: If you are curious, the reason why am fetching 3 million rows is because I was able to do this in around 20 seconds and doing it in a loop take minutes. Also the RAM usage does spike up by 1 GB or so, but it can be managed.

Comment: I admit I am not expert, but from the page you linked, it makes me think that as I suspected __A communication packet is a single SQL statement sent to the MySQL server, a single row that is sent to the client, or a binary log event sent from a master replication server to a slave.__ The interesting part is the use of the words **single** So the PacketSize need only be large enough for a single query or single Result Row

Comment: Hmmm... You do have a point @RiggsFolly. 

Basically what you are saying is unless a single row size does not exceed the packet size it would always be able to fetch it, no matter the number of resulting rows. I'll try this on my local machine by reducing the max_allowed_packet to a few KBs and then test around it.

Comment: I would be interested in what you discover